# Animatedcontainer | Animated Based on Child's Height

Tags: flutter

I would like to animate the container height based on Child's height, Is that possible?

please see the example below ... Card > Column > [Container , Animatedcontainer]

How to set XYZ Value on AnimatedContainer to match child's height OR takes the reset of the parent widget.

```
Widget example(){
return Card(
margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 3),
elevation: 5,
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
),
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 400,
      child: Text('Something with height 400'),
    ),
    AnimatedContainer(
    duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    width: selected ? xyz : 100.0,
    height: selected ? xyz : 100.0,
    color: selected ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
    alignment: selected ? Alignment.center : AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    child: FlutterLogo(size: 75),
  ),
  ]
 )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be missing is using setState to make Flutter re-render and start the animations:

```
AnimatedContainer(
  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
  width: selected ? xyz : 100.0,
  height: selected ? xyz : 100.0,
  color: selected ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
  alignment: selected ? Alignment.center : AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
  child: FlutterLogo(size: 75),
),
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Change dimensions'),
  onPressed: (){
    setState(() {
      selected = !selected;
    });
  },
),
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find a way to resize the container using "animation" based on child content height.

Comment: I've changed my answer to clarify what you need to do.

Comment: @L.kifa if my answer fixed your issue, remember to mark it as correct. This will help future user with the same issue.

Comment: No, it didn't answer the question actually. The question wasn't related to set state,  its related to resize the parent container based on child content height.

Comment: You need to use setState for the animation to happen.

Comment: I understand the setState "selected" to trigger the animation, but my question is about XYZ value on width and height, and how this value can be populated based on a child's height. I hope this can explain my question.

Comment: It's hard to understand. What do you want the XYZ value to be? You want to resize the parent of the animated container?

Comment: If you parent widget is a container with no defined height or width, it will take o n the dimensions of the child. If you use animated container as the child, then you should get the result you expect. This is difficult to understand because you only shared one widget, instead of both the parent and child.

Comment: I just updated the question with more code to explain the situation. Answering your questions What do you want the XYZ value to be?  To be Child's height OR dynamically calculate the child's content height. Do you want to resize the parent of the animated container? I think the example above explains more. Thank you, Joao.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to do the same using **AnimatedContainer** however, it turns out there's no way of doing so easily. Instead, you can achieve the desired results with **AnimatedSize**. So, as soon **YourChild()** height or width is changed an animation transition will be executed as specified in **curve** and **duration** parameters.

```
 AnimatedSize(
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        child: YourChild(),
 )
```